# On `animationend` I am increasing the `animation-duration` of an animation that should run only once. Why it does rerun again and again?

Tags: css, css-animations

On `animationend` I am increasing the `animation-duration` of an animation that should run only once.

Can someone please explain why it does rerun and start the animation again?
I would expect the animation to run only once!

It seems the following iteration does not run for the full duration, but the new duration minus the previous one.

Repro:
https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-field-4hddws?file=/index.html  (repro on mac os: chrome, firefox, safari)

(Why am I doing that? I'm just trying to get the simplest repro of this behaviour I notice while working on something more complex, and I want to understand.)

Thank you!

Comment: If I'm increasing the duration not immediately (requestAnimationFrame) after the animation end, then it works as I expect.

https://codesandbox.io/s/animationend-requestanimationframe-p3hqmz?file=/index.html